# Как преобразовать jq в чистый js?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который использует jq. Не хотелось бы загружать библиотеку , только из-за нескольких строк кода. 
Помогите преобразовать код в чистый js.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.historyAPI').on('click', function(e){      
        // отменяем стандартное действие при клике
        e.preventDefault();
        // Получаем адрес страницы
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        // Передаем адрес страницы в функцию
        getContent(href, true);
    });
});

// Добавляем обработчик события popstate, происходящего при нажатии на кнопку назад/вперед в браузере  
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    // Передаем текущий URL
    getContent(location.pathname, false);
});

// Функция загрузки контента
function getContent(url, addEntry) {
    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
        // Обновление только текстового содержимого в блоке
        $('#content').html($(data).find("#content").html());
        $('#content2').html($(data).find("#content2").html());
        // Если был выполнен клик в меню - добавляем запись в стек истории сеанса
        // Если была нажата кнопка назад/вперед, добавлять записи в историю не надо
        if(addEntry == true) {
            // Добавляем запись в историю, используя pushState
            history.pushState(null, null, url); 
        }
    });
}
```

**Пока что получилось вот так:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByClassName('historyAPI'), function(e) {

       // отменяем стандартное действие при клике
        e.preventDefault();
        // Получаем адрес страницы
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        // Передаем адрес страницы в функцию
        getContent(href, true);

});



// Добавляем обработчик события popstate, происходящего при нажатии на кнопку назад/вперед в браузере  
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    // Передаем текущий URL
    getContent(location.pathname, false);
});

// Функция загрузки контента
function getContent(url, addEntry) {
    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
        // Обновление только текстового содержимого в сером блоке
        $('#content').html($(data).find("#content").html());
        $('#content2').html($(data).find("#content2").html());
        // Если был выполнен клик в меню - добавляем запись в стек истории сеанса
        // Если была нажата кнопка назад/вперед, добавлять записи в историю не надо
        if(addEntry == true) {
            // Добавляем запись в историю, используя pushState
            history.pushState(null, null, url); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: на нативном js может выйти даже больше кода чем с библиотекой. + jQ помогает в разработке (с ним проще писать). Не советую его менять. jQ не так много места занимает, учитывая что он сам написан на нативном js. То что вы напишете сами уже компактно написано за Вас.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Просто в данном конкретном слуыае хотелось бы посмотреть на скорость загрузки и прорисовки. Убирая библиотеку, сокращаю время на 100мс, Это 25% от полной загрузки страницы. Без библиотеки - 300, с ней - 400мс.

Comment: в данном случае библиотека будет загружаться один раз и храниться в кеше браузера и загружаться и соответственно нагрузки как таковой не будет.

Comment: Вот про первую загрузку и идет речь.

Comment: Можно попробовать собрать свою версию библиотеки, включив в нее только нужны вам модули. Я так уже [развлекался](https://github.com/mayorovp/codegolf/blob/9ce566201f8ae47879841ef9c66ba5ca9521cb82/src/table.js): муторно, но работает. Нужен только browserify или webpack какой-нибудь чтобы собрать выбранные вами файлы в один.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    $('.historyAPI').on('click', function(e){
  
        // отменяем стандартное действие при клике
        e.preventDefault();
        // Получаем адрес страницы
        
  var href = this.getAttribute('href');
        // Передаем адрес страницы в функцию
        getContent(href, true);
    });
});`
В первой части код получилось так, работает, но не могу с этой строкой разобраться - $('.historyAPI').on('click', function(e){

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $('.historyAPI').on('click', function(e){
> ```

Лучше всё это заменить на обработку всплытия клика:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var a = e.target.closest("a.historyAPI");
  a && getContent(a.href, true);
});
```

> ```
> $.get(url).done(function(data) {
>     // Обновление только текстового содержимого в сером блоке
>     $('#content').html($(data).find("#content").html());
>     $('#content2').html($(data).find("#content2").html());
> ```

Приблизительно так:

```
fetch("url").then(function (resp) {
  return resp.text();
}).then(function (data) {
  var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, "text/html");

  for (var id of ["content", "content2"]) {
    var dest = document.getElementById(id);
    var elem = doc.getElementById(id);

    if (elem) {
      dest.parentElement.replaceChild(elem, dest);
    } else {
      dest.textContent = "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Что-то с этими строками не работает код. 
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.historyAPI'), function(e) { и fetch("url")...

Comment: @РинатАуди, не работает где? В хроме работает? Перепиши на ES5 и подключи полифилы для массивов, а также пормисы и fetch.

Comment: В хроме как раз не работает.

Comment: Или не заморачиваться и оставить как есть? Просто целая библиотека грузится всего из-за двух строк кода. Больше она на сайте нигде не фигурирует.

Comment: Странно, должно работать. Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: При клике по ссылкам с классом .historyAPI не происходит перехода по ссылке, контент не изменяется.

Консоль выдает:
Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at script.js:5
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:2)
/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: А, тьфу, точно. Но это значит, что твой вариант кода тоже не работал. Сейчас вообще по-другому напишу.

Comment: @РинатАуди, переделал, правда, на обработку всплытия, а не на добавления обработчика всем, как это было в оригинальном коде.

Comment: Благодарю. Заработало. При замене кода $.get... на fetch('url')...

консоль выдает: script.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at script.js:23 

ссылка в адресной строке не меняется, содержимое контента очищается.

Comment: @РинатАуди, значит элемента с таким id в dom'е нет.

Comment: @РинатАуди, исправил баг, но от отсутствия элемента это вряд ли поможет.

Comment: @РинатАуди, ещё поменял замену - думаю, теперь должно заработать.

Comment: Не хочет.
`fetch("url").then(function (resp) {
  return resp.text();
}).then(function (data) {
  var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, "text/html");`
Добавил только этот код, не заменяя то что дальше идет, в адресной строке ссылки меняются, но содержимое контента исчезает при клике на ссылки.

Comment: @РинатАуди, содержимое не может исчезать от этого кода (который в твоём комментарии). Ставь в devtools breakpoint на node removal, и смотри, кто это делает.

Comment: Неправильно выразился. Не исчезает, а не грузится контент.  Спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66952/discussion-between---and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 3):

1. `$()` - в контексте получения массива элементов и `.find()` можно заменить на [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll);
2. `attr()` - меняется на [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes);
3. `$.get` - на [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (ссылка на английском);

Естественно будет это все работать только если вы ориентируетесь на относительно новые браузеры

Comment: `$(data)` - тут парсинг html-разметки

Comment: @Qwertiy Не увидел этот контекст